# How to fetch JSON at function level and display on HTML Page in Angular2

Tags: typescript

**How can I print the data in Var jsonText on the HTML page.**
How we access the data in the local variables and print it on the HTML page.? Any method by which we can access all the local data ??
This is the code to parse CSV data to JSON and then obtain the data ...

```
export class ProductListComponent  {


        }
ngOnInit(): void { 

}

 public fileChangeEvent(event: any){
      if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
      let text = reader.result;
      this.finalDataToBePassed(text);
      return JSON.stringify(text);
  };

  reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);

    }
} 


public finalDataToBePassed(text:any){
 var lines = text.split("\n");
      var duplicates= [];
      var result = []; 
      var counts = {};
      var headers = lines[0].split(",");
      for (var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
          var line = lines[i];
        // Line breaks where messing up with the ADDRESS property. 
        //Just removing  all line breaks before using the strings
          line = line.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
          lines[i] = line;
            var obj = {};
            var currentline = lines[i].split(",");
             for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
          var header = headers[j];
          header = header.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
          headers[j] = header;
          obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
        }
        result.push(obj);
    }
    var jsonText= JSON.stringify(result); // printing this to HTML page when the scope is local ?????

return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I see that all your functions are outside of your class component. They should be inside. Actually, I don't know how is it that you don't get a compilation error.

Secondly there is no scope in Angular2. What you mean is how to make a variable accessible to the HTML/view of the component.

You can do this by declaring a variable like this:

```
export class ProductListComponent  {
private myJson: any;

public fileChangeEvent(event: any){
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = () => {
    let text = reader.result;
    this.myJson = this.finalDataToBePassed(text); //this is where you give a value to your class variable 
    return JSON.stringify(text);
 };

 reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);

 }
} 

....
}
```

Then, afterwards you go to your view/html and display it using interpolation ( eg. {{myJson}} ) or other techniques.

Hope this helps.